# GIT removing files in symlinked folders, adds them back on second run of git add -A

Tags: git, symlink, git-add

I have a directory structure as such:

```
-main
    -sym-linked-dir
        some-file.txt
        some-other-file.bar
    -sym-linked-dir-2
        -some-dir
            some-doubly-nested-file.foo
    -normal-folder
        spam.eggs
        pan.cakes
        hash.browns
```

I do *not* have any symlinked **files** at all, just symlinked folders.

Lets say I make a change to spam.eggs, I then go to the command line and do a `git add -A` - git will run as normal, but say that all the files in symlinked folders will be marked as deleted:

```
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    deleted:    main/sym-linked-dir/some-file.txt
    deleted:    main/sym-linked-dir/some-other-file.bar
    deleted:    main/sym-linked-dir-2/some-dir/some-doubly-nested-file.foo
    modified:   main/normal-folder/spam.eggs

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    main/sym-linked-dir/
    main/sym-linked-dir-2
```

When I then run `git add -A` again or `git add main/sym-linked-dir`, it will add the folder and all the files as normal, as expected.

However, if I then run **ANOTHER** `git add -A`, it will *remove* the files again, alternately.

E.g., if I did `git add main/sym-linked-dir`, it would add that, and I would only have 1 untracked change, and 1 deleted file + folder. If I then do a `git add -A` it would *untrack* `main/sym-linked-dir` but recognise once again that it had been tracking `sym-linked-dir-2` all along. I do another `git add -A` and the situation reverses again!

My config for the repo (in .git folder) is as follows:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    symlinks = true
    ignorecase = true
    hideDotFiles = dotGitOnly
```

I have nothing else relevent in my global config.

My overall question is: **How do I get git to reliably treat files in symlinked folders as regular files, for all intents and purposes, so that confusing behaviour such as the above, doesn't happen?**

**edit:**

My use case is that I have a module that is used by two (or more) repos **locally**, so to keep them updated with each other with the latest code, I just symlinked some directories in both cases - this means whenever I update it in one repo, it updates in any of the others, e.g.

```
-myAwesomeModules
    -myModule
        some-file.txt

-app1
    -modules
        -myModule <points to /myAwesomeModules/myModule>
            some-file.txt

-app2
    -modules
        -myModule <also points to /myAwesomeModules/myModule>
            some-file.txt
```

Comment: This looks like a git bug.  But regarding your overall question, that may not be easy.  Git wants to track symbolic links explicitly, not follow them.

Comment: Which version of `git` on which platform?

Comment: @TriskalJM ```git version 1.9.5.msysgit.1``` on Windows 10

Comment: @TavianBarnes hmm..I have to believe, though, that this is what the symlinks option in the config is explicitly for?

Comment: Seems like a bug in msysgit (where symlink support is probably a bit iffy, given that I am told symlinks only exist on NT file systems).  It seems perhaps to be adding the symlink as a symlink sometimes, necessitating removal of the directory contents, then following the symlink the other times and putting all symlinked-to files in as actual files.  Note that the existing (`HEAD`) commit clearly has the symlinked-dir files as real files, not as a symlink, so if you've ever checked that out, git may have replaced the symlink with a real directory at some point.

Comment: @HarryMustoe-Playfair That just allows git to create symlinks on your filesystem if the repo you cloned contains them.  git always wants to track symlinks explicitly (i.e., it will remember that some path in your repo *is* a symlink).

Answer (score 0):

After updating my version of git to the latest version, it appeared to not be following symlinked folders to files at all.

I'm posting this here for others to see.

I am using `git version 2.8.1.windows.1`

The **only** solution I could come up with was to turn the symlinks into junctions instead using `MKLINK /J` on the command line.

This turned the folders into ntfs junctions, which git happily follows and treats the files inside as regular files.

I personally used the handy [Link Shell Extension](http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/linkshellextension.html) to do this easily.

--- more information ---

This is okay for my use case, as I just had files outside the repo that I wanted to include in several repos and have them update each other, irrespective of what other developers on the project were doing.

This is *not* a solution if you want to properly version control these files separately from your repo - for that, I believe, submodules would be the answer.

If you want to use symlinks to another directory then git which track the symlinks themselves, **not** the files, so other developers on the project would have to add those symlinks themselves.